# Snowflake masking policy with external function support on GCP

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I want to externally tokenize some columns before loading to snowflake. Later I want to use a masking policy to de-tokenize the column using an external function. Is this possible to be done in snowflake on gcp or is this currently supported only on aws?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, external functions are supported on both platforms